# Create a Hive (0.10) table for schema data using Parquet Fileformat

Tags: mapreduce, nested, hive, avro, parquet

I want to export data from server to hive.
I have a 3 level nested data in form of java classes.
I was successfully able to create a avro schema using Avro Tools ReflectData and write out the data in avro files using ReflectDatumWriter. In Hive I was able to create a table and specified the schema using the

```
TBLPROPERTIES 
  ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///schema.avsc');
```

I can see there are way to export the same data in parquet format
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-convert-existing-data-into-parquet/

Let say I get that done and have same data in parquet files ..
How do I query this export parquet data in Hive ?
But how i specify the schema for hive ? 
I don't want to write a huge create table statement in hive with the whole nested schema. How do i specify null values for some members in schema ?
I there a way I can directly create a parquet schema like avro schema and give to Hive using create table statement ?

Answer (score 0):

To query data in hive you can create hive external table and specify location of the file. Like this

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE XXX (...) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS
  INPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat"
  OUTPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat"
  LOCATION '/you/location/here';`

There is no way to not specify this statement, because generation of file independent from hive metastore and all you can do with AVRO is just generate data file